# How to fix `failed to load command: bootsnap (/rails/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/bin/bootsnap)` while deploying through fly.io

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, precompile, fly, bootsnap

I am trying to deploy a ROR application through fly.io in Ubuntu 22.04. When I try to use fly deploy command I get following error
[Terminal Output Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4jaJW.png)

My Gemfile has following content

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.7.2'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.8'
# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.11'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'mini_racer', platforms: :ruby

# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'

# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# for user authentication
gem 'devise'

# for authorization
gem 'pundit'

# for using font awsome
gem 'font-awesome-rails'

# for applying bootstrap
gem 'bootstrap', '~> 4.1.1'

# Use ActiveStorage variant
gem 'mini_magick', '~> 4.8'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', require: false

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: %i[mri mingw x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
  # for indentation
  gem 'rubocop-rails'
end

group :test do
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  # Easy installation and use of chromedriver to run system tests with Chrome
  gem 'chromedriver-helper'
end
# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: %i[mingw mswin x64_mingw jruby]
gem "dockerfile-rails", ">= 1.5", :group => :development
gem "sentry-ruby", "~> 5.11"
gem "sentry-rails", "~> 5.11"
gem "net-smtp", "~> 0.3.3", :require => false
gem "net-imap", "~> 0.3.7", :require => false
gem "net-pop", "~> 0.1.2", :require => false
```

And my Dockerfile is

```
# syntax = docker/dockerfile:1

# Make sure RUBY_VERSION matches the Ruby version in .ruby-version and Gemfile
ARG RUBY_VERSION=2.7.2
FROM ruby:$RUBY_VERSION-slim as base

LABEL fly_launch_runtime="rails"

# Rails app lives here
WORKDIR /rails

# Set production environment
ENV RAILS_ENV="production" \
    BUNDLE_WITHOUT="development:test" \
    BUNDLE_DEPLOYMENT="1"

# Update gems and bundler
RUN gem update --system --no-document && \
    gem install -N bundler

# Install packages needed to install nodejs
RUN apt-get update -qq && \
    apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y curl && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists /var/cache/apt/archives

# Install Node.js
ARG NODE_VERSION=18.17.0
ENV PATH=/usr/local/node/bin:$PATH
RUN curl -sL https://github.com/nodenv/node-build/archive/master.tar.gz | tar xz -C /tmp/ && \
    /tmp/node-build-master/bin/node-build "${NODE_VERSION}" /usr/local/node && \
    rm -rf /tmp/node-build-master


# Throw-away build stage to reduce size of final image
FROM base as build

# Install packages needed to build gems and node modules
RUN apt-get update -qq && \
    apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y build-essential libpq-dev node-gyp pkg-config python

# Build options
ENV PATH="/usr/local/node/bin:$PATH"

# Install application gems
COPY --link Gemfile Gemfile.lock ./
RUN bundle install && \
    bundle exec bootsnap precompile --gemfile && \
    rm -rf ~/.bundle/ $BUNDLE_PATH/ruby/*/cache $BUNDLE_PATH/ruby/*/bundler/gems/*/.git

# Install node modules
COPY --link package.json ./
RUN npm install

# Copy application code
COPY --link . .

# Precompile bootsnap code for faster boot times
RUN bundle exec bootsnap precompile app/ lib/

# Precompiling assets for production without requiring secret RAILS_MASTER_KEY
RUN SECRET_KEY_BASE=DUMMY ./bin/rails assets:precompile


# Final stage for app image
FROM base

# Install packages needed for deployment
RUN apt-get update -qq && \
    apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y curl imagemagick postgresql-client && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists /var/cache/apt/archives

# Copy built artifacts: gems, application
COPY --from=build /usr/local/bundle /usr/local/bundle
COPY --from=build /rails /rails

# Run and own only the runtime files as a non-root user for security
RUN useradd rails --create-home --shell /bin/bash && \
    chown -R rails:rails db log storage tmp
USER rails:rails

# Deployment options
ENV RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT="1" \
    RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES="true"

# Entrypoint prepares the database.
ENTRYPOINT ["/rails/bin/docker-entrypoint"]

# Start the server by default, this can be overwritten at runtime
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["./bin/rails", "server"]
```

I have also attached my config/boots.rb file which is

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE'] ||= File.expand_path('../Gemfile', __dir__)

require 'bundler/setup' # Set up gems listed in the Gemfile.
require 'bootsnap/setup' # Speed up boot time by caching expensive operations.
```

I have so far tried a plenty of different operations but none of them have worked so far. I read somewhere that it might fixed by deleteing the tmp/cache folder so I deleted that but nothing worked even then. After that I tried to list the version of bootsnap to be installed but still no progress. I have also tried to update the gems by using the command of bundle install but I am not able to fix the issue.

Comment: Don't use images for error messages -- include the messages as text in your question.

Comment: When I tried to add it via text I was not able to post my question because stackoverflow was showing an error that my post mostly contains the code.

Comment: Ah! it's you cache issue just clean you cache and re-run it.